# How to Manage Time/Date Schedules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm putting together a tool that allows a user to generate reports for a class of students. I'd like to incorporate report "periods" or "schedules" but I'm unsure of how to do so.

Essentially, I want the user to assign an evaluation "schedule" to each class, i.e. from the 5th of one month to the 4th of the next. Thus, reports will (and must) be run for sequential periods. However, I do want the user to be able to adjust the end period of the schedule for a student on an ad hoc basis.

I thought of creating a "schedules" table, but I'm not sure of how to store the start and end dates so the cycle can be repeated. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I've used [ice_cube](http://seejohnrun.github.com/ice_cube/) ([GitHub project](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube/)) with some success. The module handles recurrences well, it's got its own serializer/deserializer, and it's well-documented.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a report model/table with a start day and end day (such as 4 and 5) and use that to set the date with. This would persist to the database normally, but for a one off report that doesn't need to be stored, you could just create a new report with a different end date.

I.E., you have a reports table for persistent reports (A report for an entire class of students), but don't save your individual reports.

Comment: As opposed to specifying the start and end dates, how about specifying the current period start date and the duration (# of days). And with every run of the report, the current period would be updated. Does that approach make sense?

Comment: That depends on your use case--if the idea is that the report runs exactly once at the close of each time period, then it does make sense. In that case, you wouldn't need a report object in the database, you would probably set the values on the "class of students" object. To run the reporting for a single student over a time period, you could call the report method in the class of students controller with different params (I.E. the class_roster is the one student, etc)